# How can I set a variable to specify ARRAY in ispsoft

Tags: plc, delta, ladder-logic

I want to put the variable D1, for example, instead of the number 1 in this code
The program does not accept this
`MOV D100 Ary[1]`

The program does not accept this
MOV D100 Ary[D1]

I tried a lot and did not succeed. I will be grateful to you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [ISPSoft User Manual](https://filecenter.deltaww.com/Products/download/06/060301/Manual/DELTA_IA-PLC_ISPSoft_UM_EN_20200312.pdf), item 6.1.5:

> In ISPSoft, a symbol can be modified by an index register (...) The same rule applies to a symbol whose data type is ARRAY. The format is
> `Identifier[Index]@Index register`. The `index` must be a constant. If the index is a symbol, the symbol whose data type is ARRAY cannot be modified by the index register (...)

[image]

> In the figure below, Ary is an array composed of five elements, and the start device address is `D200`. When the system compiles the program, `D200~D204` are assigned Ary. If the value in the index register `E0` is `2`, `Ary[0]@E0` indicates that `2` is added to the device address (`D200`) assigned to
> `Ary[0]`, that is, `Ary[0]@E0` represents `D202`, the device address assigned to `Ary[2]`. If the value in the index register `E0` is `6`, `Ary[0]@E0` represents `D206`. `D206` is not within the range of devices assigned to the array, but this usage is legal. (...)

Note that the method depends on the PLC model, there are some that do not support the use of index, you can check in the manual.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the program installed now, but I have already used this feature on a DVPSA2. The manual is well explained, try creating a variable in the global list pointing to E0 and using it in your Array in the same way (`Ary[0]E0`)... maybe it will work using `D1` instead of `E0`.

Comment: What PLC model are you using? Can you include a snapshot of your program in your question?

Comment: delta dvp-14ss2

Comment: It finally worked, the error was in the index
Thank you